# Problem with writing and reading csv files in R

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

This is my transaction data:

```
head(data)

id          from_id        to_id      amount    date_trx
<fctr>      <fctr>         <fctr>     <dbl>     <date>
226133      7468           5695       700.0     2005-01-04
779717      6213           9379       11832.0   2005-01-08
264887      7517           8170       1000.0    2005-01-10
830594      6143           9845       4276.0    2005-01-12
452670      6254           9640       200.0     2005-01-14
268574      6669           5815       200.0     2005-01-20

...
```

also

```
class(data)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

typeof(data)
[1] "list"
```

I saved it as a csv file, for later use, to my computer via:

```
write.csv(data, "mydirectory/dataset.csv")
```

and read it via:

```
data_read <- read.csv("mydirectory/dataset.csv") %>% select(-X)
```

also

```
class(data_read)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

typeof(data_read)
[1] "list"
```

However, when I want to get the values of 1st column in "data" with:

```
data[,1]
```

It returns:

```
[1] 226133 779717 264887 830594 452670 268574 ...
```

But, the same command in "data_read":

```
data_read[,1]
```

returns the column itself:

```
 id
<fctr>
226133              
779717              
264887              
830594              
452670              
268574
...
```

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
data[,1,drop=F]
```

Also, one looks like a dataframe and the other is a tibble.